# Oracle - How to turn rows into columns "in pairs"

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table that basically lists field names and their values, but each attribute and value is in a separate row. In the example below, the table lists product codes and their prices.

```
create table attributes_list(attribute_name varchar2(50), attribute_value number);
insert into attributes_list values ('product_a_code', 10);
insert into attributes_list values ('product_b_code', 11);
insert into attributes_list values ('product_c_code', 12);
insert into attributes_list values ('product_a_price', 10.99);
insert into attributes_list values ('product_b_price', 20.99);
insert into attributes_list values ('product_c_price', 30.99);
```

[image: original table]

Is it possible to turn these rows into columns, but in a way where I can link the prices to the product codes?

[image: resulting table]

PS. I know the title is not ideal, but I couldn't think of a better way to make this question. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Not unless you have a have column that ties the attributes together for a given product.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, can you give me an example of the values this new column should have?

Comment: @Geralt, if you're seriously using the above as a database design I urge you to reconsider. Look at the accepted answer and think for a moment: all that for a Product/Price list, the simplest query imaginable. What will happen when you want to do some real queries? Please Google "inner platform effect". Others have tried this. They've all failed, badly.

Comment: @EdGibbs not my choice, but fortunately this design was used on this table only (for some reason)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a query that {1} finds all rows whose ATTRIBUTE_NAMEs ends in '_code', and {2} finds all rows whose ATTRIBUTE_NAMEs ends in '_price'.  {3} JOIN the 2 result sets ON the product names, which can be found via SUBSTR().

```
select 
  T1.attribute_value as product_code
, T2.attribute_value as product_price
from (                                    -- {1}
  select attribute_name, attribute_value 
  from attributes_list
  where attribute_name like '%_code'
) T1 join (                               -- {2}
  select attribute_name, attribute_value 
  from attributes_list
  where attribute_name like '%_price'
) T2
  -- {3} 
  on substr( T1.attribute_name, 1, length( T1.attribute_name ) - length( '_code' ) ) 
   = substr( T2.attribute_name, 1, length( T2.attribute_name ) - length( '_price' ) )
;

-- result
   PRODUCT_CODE    PRODUCT_PRICE 
_______________ ________________ 
             10            10.99 
             11            20.99 
             12            30.99
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f4d77736ed107ec0b4919ee05faf6d6).

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE() - as in @GMB's answer - for finding the product names in the ON clause (instead of SUBSTR()).

Answer (score 1):

You need at least three columns:

```
create table attributes_list (
    product varchar2(50),
    attribute_name varchar2(50),
    attribute_value number
);
insert into attributes_list values ('a', 'code', 10);
insert into attributes_list values ('b', 'code', 11);
. . .
```

Then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when attribute_name = 'code' then value end) as code,
       max(case when attribute_name = 'price' then value end) as price
from attributes_list
group by product;
```

Answer (score 1):

If, as shown in your sample data, column `attribute_name` has a fixed format made of a product and an attribute separated by an underscore (without an underscore in the attribute name), you can use regexes and conditional aggregation, like so:

```
select
    regexp_replace(attribute_name, '_[^_]+$', '') product_name,
    max(case when regexp_substr(attribute_name, '[^_]+$') = 'code'  then attribute_value end) product_code,
    max(case when regexp_substr(attribute_name, '[^_]+$') = 'price' then attribute_value end) product_price
from attributes_list 
group by regexp_replace(attribute_name, '_[^_]+$', '')
```